# Predicting what the graph of a function looks like?

Tags: rational-functions

How can you predict what the function

$$f(x) = \frac{(x - 5)(x + 4)(x - 3)^2(x)}{(x-5)(x)}$$

looks like before you plot it?

Comment: Are you sure there are two $(x-5)$? And, $x$, too.

Comment: Yes I am @mathlove

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observations:

$$f(x) = \frac{(x - 5)(x + 4)(x - 3)^2(x)}{(x-5)(x)} = (x+4)(x-3)^2,\;\;x\neq 5, x\neq 0$$The function is not defined at $x = 0, x= 5$. Why not? These are called, however, removable discontinuities, and do not impact the graph of the function $f(x) = (x + 4)(x-3)^2, $ save for there being "holes" at $x = 5,\text{ and } x = 0$

$f(x)$ intersects the x axis at $x = -4, x = 3$.  Why? We call these values of $x$ "zeros" of the function.

The polynomial we are left with is a cubic polynomial.

We can also take the derivative to find critical points; this will help immensely when graphing: it allows us to determine where, if anywhere, there are local minimums, local maximums, etc. To find these, we compute $f'(x)$ and solve for $x$ when $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: How would taking the derivative help to find critical points?

Comment: When we take the derivative and put $f'(x) = 0$, the solutions give us the critical points: the values of $x$ at which $f(x)$ reaches local maximums and minimums (the peaks and valleys of the curve.) Note that when $f'(x) = 0$, the tangent lines to the curve have slope $0$, which means that the function, at those points, is changes between increasing to decreasing, or decreasing to increasing: I.e., the tangent lines are horizontal, like lines balancing at the top of a peak, or at the bottom of a valley in the curve.

Comment: Note, it's also possible that $f'(x)=0$ but $f$ does not attain a local max or min at $x$. To check this, one should first check $f''(x)$. If $f''(x)=0$ then one should check values close enough to $x$ that there are no other critical points near by.

Comment: @amWhy: Needs another UV +1

Answer (score 0):

Hint: When is the denominator $0$? When is the numerator $0$ and what does this mean for the graph (you should consider limits of $f$ as $x$ tends to these zeros)? What are the turning points of a function and how can you find them, and their characteristics (minimum, maximum, saddle point)? Before you do any of this though, you should make sure nothing cancels (removable discontinuities).